# How to setup a mock for an interpolated string?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, string-interpolation

Let's say I have a logger interface implementation that has a Trace method on it, like such:

```
public interface IMyLogger
{
    void Trace(string message, params object[] parameters);
}

public class MyLogger : IMyLogger
{
    public void Trace(string message, params object[] parameters)
    {
        // Writes the trace to a log file somewhere
    }
}
```

And a method call using this logger call with an interpolated string like so:

```
public class MyWorker
{
    private IMyLogger Logger { get; set; }

    public MyWorker(IMyLogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoSomeWork(int x)
    {
        Logger.Trace($"Value of x is {x}");
    }
}
```

I'm writing a unit test for the DoSomeWork method. This is what I have right now, and the test passes:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoSomeWork_ShouldLogTrace()
{
    var mockLogger = new Mock<IMyLogger>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    mockLogger.Setup(l => l.Trace("Value of x is 5", It.IsAny<object[]>());

    var testWorker = new MyWorker();
    testWorker.DoSomeWork(5);
}
```

My question is: is there a way I can pass the interpolated string to the Trace setup instead of the result of the string interpolation?

Comment: I would guess not

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  You could do `int x = 5;` then pass `$"Value of x is {x}"` to the mock.

Comment: Perhaps parameterizing the method is one way to go. Unfortunatelly not so easy with MSTest. xUnit have the notion of [Theory].

Comment: You can use data sources for MSTest, too. However it is not as trivial as for NUnit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759510/5114784

Comment: I would recommend you educate yourself on (unit) testing, as what you want to do is copy implementation details. You should test *behavior* and *results*, not code flow. What if you change the `DoSomeWork` method to call `Logger.Trace(string.Format(...))`? It will work just as well, but your test will break. What have you gained by that?

Comment: Short answer is **No**. the setup expression will only be looking at the resulting string. It has no concern with string interpolation.

Comment: @juharr: that makes sense. This is more along the lines of what I was originally asking for.

Comment: @MarioDS: there are many instances in the application I write with my current employer where they want specific log messages to be written in certain cases. Thus, we have unit tests that make sure for any given input, we get an expected output. You are correct that there is definitely a more appropriate way to unit test this, this was more of an example question. It's for this reason that I want to mark Paulo's answer as the correct one, though the verify presents the same problem. Not doing verify works for my specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way I can pass the interpolated string to the Trace setup instead of the result of the string interpolation?

No. C# interpolated string is not a templating engine but a compile-time feature.

This line

```
Logger.Trace($"Value of x is {x}");
```

will call the `Trace` method with the formatted message and no parameters.

So use either the classic placeholders or use a logger engine, which processes template parameters such as [Serilog](https://serilog.net/).

Comment: `System.FormattableString` into which an expression like `$" ... "` is implicitly convertible,  comes close to what you call "a templating engine" (possibly see my new answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass an interpolated string but you can verify that the `Trace` method was called with the value you expected.

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoSomeWork_ShouldLogWarning()
{
    var mockLogger = new Mock<IMyLogger>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    mockLogger.Setup(l => l.Trace(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()));

    var testWorker = new MyWorker(mockLogger.Object);

    const int expectedValue = 5;

    testWorker.DoSomeWork(expectedValue);

    mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Trace($"Value of x is {expectedValue}"));
}
```

Comment: The verify will fail because you left out the params parameter. It is needed just as with the setup on the mock

Comment: I tested the code before posting the answer. params is optional

Comment: Understood. Usually when parameters are omitted Moq tends to complain.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FormattableString` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring) in namespace `System`.

That is, if you can have an overload:

```
void Trace(FormattableString formattableMessage);
```

and make sure this is used, then a call like:

```
Logger.Trace($"Value of x is {x}");
```

will produce a "rich" object where you can inspect `.Format` and `.GetArguments` etc.

The explanation is that a compile-time expression `$" ... "` is **implicitly convertible** to the special type `FormattableString` which does not "interpolate" right away, but instead keeps track of the format and each argument. In the implementation `// Writes the trace to a log file somewhere`, use `.ToString()` on this rich object to have the actual interpolation performed.

Then the Moq setup would be similar to:

```
// using nice Strict mock
mockLogger.Setup(l => l.Trace(It.Is(
  (FormattableString x) => x.Format == "Value of x is {0}"
  )));
```

Edited: Must use `{0}` with index `0` in the mock setup, not `{x}`.